# XML Oracle CROSS JOIN

Tags: xml, oracle, join, plsql, cross-join

I have a problem with the tranfer of the content of an XML file in Oracle. 
I'm able to extract the values from the XMLfiles which I store in a table.
The problem is related to the correct extraction of data when I mix the levels.

Here the code which I use:

```
select count(*)

from testtable2 t
cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
 'records/REC'
  passing t.xml_file 
  columns 
          CD_UID varchar2(200) path 'UID',
        --     names xmltype path 'static_data/summary',
          identifi xmltype path 'dynamic_data/cluster_related'

) RecUid


cross join  xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
  'cluster_related/identifiers/identifier[@type="issn"]'
  passing RecUid.identifi
  columns 
     CD_ISSN_NO varchar2(200) path '@value'
    )   Issn  ;
```

The expected results is 20471, but merging with the Issn I get only 18896 lines.
I guess it means that it's taking in account only the records where I have the CD_ISSN_NO not null, but which is the correct code I should use in this case?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Not quite sure what you trying to achive, however what numbers will be if you run this 2 selects separetly?

Comment: if i run the 2 separately I have for the first one 20471 and for the second onr 18896

Comment: what i'M trying to achive is a table with CD_UID and CD_ISSN_NO which contains not only "not null rows" but all the CD_UID where are also null values of CD_ISSN_NO

Comment: Well, to make your cross join query work, you should replace second `cross join` keyword with comma, so it should look like 'CROSS JOIN table1, table2'. But for your query it will give you N*M records, something like 386820016. I guess in fact you want some join criteria, like a rows with columns cd_uid and cd_issn_no. So you need some column to identify record and this column you can use for outer join.